# How to style two MUI Sliders in two different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Im trying to style two sliders, each in different react component.

slider in the first component

```
const muiThemeSlider1 = createTheme({
    overrides:{
      MuiSlider: {
        thumb:{
            color: "#4442a9",
            marginTop: '-10px',
            width:'30px',
            height: '30px',
            border: '4px solid white',
        },
```

and JSX goes like this

```
<ThemeProvider theme={muiThemeSlider1}>
     <Slider
         defaultValue = {6}
         value = {value}
         onChange = {handleSliderChange}
         step = {1}
         min = {1}
         max = {20}
         marks = {false}
         valueLabelDisplay = "on"
     />             
</ThemeProvider>
```

slider in the 2nd component

```
const muiThemeSlider2 = createTheme({
    overrides:{
      MuiSlider: {
        thumb:{
            color: "#4442a9",
            marginTop: '-10px',
            width:'30px',
            height: '30px',
            border: '4px solid white',
        },
```

and JSX goes like this

```
<ThemeProvider theme={muiThemeSlider2}>
     <Slider
         defaultValue = {50}
         value = {value}
         onChange = {handleSliderChange}
         step = {1}
         min = {1}
         max = {100}
         marks = {false}
         valueLabelDisplay = "on"
     />             
</ThemeProvider>
```

doesnt matter what changes i make, its always applied for both sliders.
thanks

Comment: What version of MUI are you using, V4 or V5? "createTheme" is syntax for V5, previously in V4 it used to be called "createMuiTheme", but the structure of the theme object you're using is for V4, but it has changed for V5. The new structure should be `createTheme({ components: { MuiSlider: { styleOverrides: { ... }}})` instead of `createTheme({ overrides: { MuiSlider: { ... }}})`

Answer (score 0):

you can give that properties inside sx prop, if you are using v5

```
<Slider
         defaultValue = {50}
         value = {value}
         onChange = {handleSliderChange}
         step = {1}
         min = {1}
         max = {100}
         marks = {false}
         valueLabelDisplay = "on"
         sx={{
          thumb: {
              // your styles here
}

}}
     />
```